# flock command script fail on xunbuntu 16.04 - cant understad why

Tags: xubuntu, syntax, flock

```
#!/bin/bash
( 
  flock -n 200 || exit 1
  # commands executed under lock 
  sleep 3
  echo "TEST"
) 200 > /home/nis/Scripts/lock.txt
```

Running this scrip gets me this error:

```
lock.sh: 7: lock.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

I don't get why this happens. It works on my QNAP (Busybox)

Comment: xhienne's answer addresses your main problem, but looking at this I wonder if it's doing what you want.  If all you want is to ensure the process only runs one at a time, that will work, but it would be almost useless for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Suppress the space after `200`:

```
...
) 200> /home/nis/Scripts/lock.txt
```

What `200>` does is to redirect file descriptor 200 to the given file. You then use that file descriptor with `flock` to lock the file.

Comment: thanks.but no change - samme error
also tried Sudo. Same error. :/

Comment: @Nis Start over with a brand new file: copy-paste your script except the last line, then copy-paste the last line from my answer. It should work (works for me)

Comment: I was so hoping for this to work.
I wrote the whole thing in a new file.
However, I wrote the script on a mac (EditRocket) and saved on samba network drive, then changed permissions (777 just to be sure)
but..let me try to do it from scratch locally..

Comment: No. Same thing. Really frustrating.
Could i have installed the "wrong" flock?
its:
flock -V : flock from util-linux 2.27.1

Comment: ok, this adds to my confusion.
If I run this as "bash 'scriptname.sh" then there are no troubles..
anyne can explain this? (and whats the difference between sh and bash calling the script?)
Thanks

Comment: @Nis Your script is being executed by `/bin/sh`. Is `#!/bin/bash` really the first line? Check with `hexdump` (`hd your.script.sh`) or `od` (`od -ctx1 your.script.sh`) that you haven't a [Unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning. And if this is the case, trash your text editor ;-)

Comment: I used a different editor, new file. That worked.
Still strange:)
Thanks!!